# Heroku and ip mask

Tags: security, heroku

I'm building a shopping site which uses a service which allows credit card payments (tranzilla), the service is requiring an IP or IP mask from which it will allow requests (by sockets). The problem is that I'm using heroku as hosting, which is decentralized...
Is there any way to do this? (except buying the custom ssl add-on, which is my last resort and not the best solution)
P.S. full IP mask is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  you can use a [hosted VPN service](http://www.optimumbusiness.com/online/static.jsp?bsp=g7&s_cid=oblfgsip&s_kwcid=TC|7817|static%20ip||S||3748072602) to maintain a static IP Address in which to contact tranzilla.   A proxy server might also work,  however,  using a public proxy server would be a bad idea.

Comment: Wow, didn't think about that :)  
a nice solution, thank you.
we are actually not that concerned about security or performance (in worst case someone will hack and pay us more money :) ) so we can use any cheap dedicated server we want, important part is that it will have a static IP...  
Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a new Heroku add-on called Proximo that gives you a static outbound IP address to connect to services with IP whitelists! At this time it's in private beta, and there is no pricing info available yet, but it seems like a promising solution: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo

Comment: Nice solution, but too expensive, more expensive than having a small proxy on amazon ec2 :)

Comment: Has anyone been able to get Proximo working with a Rails 4 app? I tried the using the Proximo wrapper, but was met with a `No App` error after deploying.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apigee to wrap the API in question - http://app.apigee.com/, and make your API call through Apigee instead of directly to the API in question.   Then enter the IP that the Apigee call comes from, and you're set.