# Django and Heroku - POST(https) to API using static IP address

Tags: django, static, https, heroku, ip

I have a django app deployed on heroku that needs to make POST requests to a https API with a static ip address.

Whats the simple way to get a proxy to do just that ?

Are there any paid alternatives ?

which kind of squid setup should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231391/heroku-and-ip-mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new beta addon which essentially does exactly what you are asking, you can check it out here: https://addons.heroku.com/proximo (proximo).

Comment: It just looks VERY expensive!