# Is it possible to whitelist Heroku apps?

Tags: heroku, whitelist

I have a Heroku application that binds with a telco sms gateway via SMPP
The telco guys need to whitelist IPs for my app to connect.
I am aware of the new addon proximo, but it's just insanely priced. So that option is out.
Is there a subnet or a list of IPs that I can get whitelisted and is there a guarantee that all requests from my app will originate from tose IPs?
I found this https://api.heroku.com/vendor/logplex/allowlist.
Is that only for syslog or all apps make a request from one of those IPs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Even though an external VPN or the proximo addon are a solution in case you want to whitelist a Heroku app, I have decided to go for the simpler option and host the SMPP binding service of my app on ec2 using an Elastic IP

Comment: what service did you decide on for your ec2 instance? i assume you are running some sort of forward proxy?

Answer (score 9):

There is now a Heroku add-on that does this called Proximo: https://addons.heroku.com/proximo

Answer (score 6):

The Heroku docs specifically mention how [dynos don't have static IP addresses](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#isolation-and-security). Even when using custom domains it looks like they want you to [point to a CNAME record](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-should-i-use-to-point-my-custom-domain-to-heroku) rather than an IP address. So if you need a static IP it looks like Proximo is your best bet.

Would it be possible to use an API token to authenticate your app with the sms gateway, similar to the way the [blitz.ip plugin](http://support.blitz.io/kb/integration/integration-using-heroku-with-blitz) works with heroku? Then you might not need to use a static IP whitelist.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231391/heroku-and-ip-mask) looks to be doing something similar to you, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2231667/28037) suggests using a hosted VPN service. Would that work?

Comment: I cant use an API token, the telco guys are pretty adamant about IP whitelisting only! Hosted VPN might be an option, I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Heroku now has Private Spaces which is what you are looking for:

https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces

Answer (score 4):

Another Heroku addon option is [Quotaguard](https://addons.heroku.com/quotaguardstatic) , in beta, free for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can host a proxy yourself using Dockhero Heroku add-on - https://dockhero.io/ - which has a static IP (AWS elastic IP).

1. Install the add-on and the CLI plugin:

   ```
   $ heroku addons:create dockhero
   $ heroku plugins:install dockhero
   ```
2. Wait until the provisioning is done and get DOCKHERO_HOST environment variable

   ```
   $ heroku dh:wait
   $ heroku config:get DOCKHERO_HOST
   --> e.g. dockhero-spherical-42047.dockhero.io
   ```
3. Create **dockhero-compose.yml** file with the following contents:

   ```
   version: "2"
   services:
     proxy:
       image: tecnativa/tcp-proxy
       environment:
         LISTEN: ":80"
         TALK: "www.wikipedia.org:80"
       ports: 
         - "80:80"
   ```

Here `www.wikipedia.org:80` is the server which you build a proxy for.
Find more about the syntax in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

4. Run this stack in the cloud using Dockhero CLI:

   ```
   $ heroku dh:compose up -d
   ```
5. Any requests to the host from DOCKHERO_HOST Heroku config var will now be proxied according to your dockhero-compose.yml

   ```
   $ curl http://dockhero-spherical-42047.dockhero.io/
   --> <response from www.wikipedia.org>
   ```

**IMPORTANT**: as of writing this, dockhero.io is in Beta and available for free. When switching to production, the assigned IP may be changed after a prior notification.

Answer (score 1):

[Fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie) is another alternative add-on not mentioned here. Free plan with 500 requests per month. Requires some adjustments in code and heroku app to be in us region (or you can migrate it: [Migrating an Application to Another Region](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration)). Worked for me.